# C++: Expand array elements as parameter of a function using boost::hana

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-hana

I discovered two months ago boost::hana. Seems very powerfull so I decided to take a look.
From the documentation I saw this examples:

```
std::string s;
hana::int_c<10>.times([&]{ s += "x"; });
```

that is equivalent to:

```
s += "x"; s += "x"; ... s += "x"; // 10 times
```

I'd like to know if it is possible (and if yes how) to write smthg like:

```
std::string s;
std::array<int, 10> xs = {1, 3, 5, ...};
hana::int_c<10>.times([&](int i){ s += std::to_string(xs[i]) + ","; });
```

a sort of "unpacking" at compile time, or even:

```
myfunction( hana::unpack<...>( xs ) );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question seems twofold. First, the title of your question asks whether it is possible to expand the elements of an array as the parameters of a function. It is indeed possible, since [`std::array`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structstd_1_1array.html) is [`Foldable`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1Foldable.html). It suffices to use `hana::unpack`:

```
#include <boost/hana/ext/std/array.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/unpack.hpp>
#include <array>
namespace hana = boost::hana;


struct myfunction {
    template <typename ...T>
    void operator()(T ...i) const {
        // whatever
    }
};

int main() {
    std::array<int, 10> xs = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}};
    hana::unpack(xs, myfunction{});
}
```

Secondly, you ask whether it is possible to do something like

```
std::string s;
std::array<int, 10> xs = {1, 3, 5, ...};
hana::int_c<10>.times([&](int i){ s += std::to_string(xs[i]) + ","; });
```

The answer to this is to use `hana::int_c<10>.times.with_index`:

```
hana::int_c<10>.times.with_index([&](int i) { s += std::to_string(xs[i]) + ","; });
```

Equivalently, you could also use `hana::for_each`:

```
hana::for_each(xs, [&](int x) { s += std::to_string(x) + ","; });
```