# boost::hana tuple unpacking for variadic template instantiation

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-hana

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711666/c-expand-array-elements-as-parameter-of-a-function-using-boosthana) I was wondering if something like this would be achievable in a straightforward way using boost::hana:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/unpack.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template<typename ... T>
struct A {};

int main() {

  auto my_tuple = hana::tuple_t<int, double, float>;

  // Is there any way to unpack my_tuple as template arguments for A?
  // Something like
  using MyStruct = A<hana::unpack_types(my_tuple)...>;

  static_assert(std::is_same<MyStruct, A<int, double, float>>::value, "Ooops!");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/5922757

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`template_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Metafunction.html#ga246419f6c3263b648412f346106e6543) to lift `A` into a metafunction, then call [`unpack`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Foldable.html#ga7b0c23944364ce61136e10b978ae2170):

```
using MyStruct = decltype(hana::unpack(my_tuple, hana::template_<A>))::type;
```

[<kbd>Example</kbd>](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4osTj1mmW3RzuBg2).

Answer (score 1):

You may do it yourself with:

```
 template <template <typename...> class C, typename Tuple> struct RebindImpl;

 template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
 struct RebindImpl<C, hana::tuple_t<Ts...>>{
     using type = C<Ts...>;
};

 template <template <typename...> class C, typename Tuple> 
 using Rebind = typename RebindImpl<C, Tuple>::type;
```

Comment: This is not going to do what you expect! `hana::tuple_t<T...>` is specified as being functionally equivalent to `hana::make_tuple(hana::type<T>{}...)`, except with a potentially different type. So first, you don't know what type you get, and second, even if you assume it to be _exactly the same as_ `hana::make_tuple(hana::type<T>{}...)`, then your solution will instantiate `C<hana::type<T>...>`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it if all you care is about getting a correct type:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr A<Args...> make_A(hana::tuple_t<Args...>) {
    return {};
}
```